# MYSQL - Nothing happen while trying to import DB from mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, dump

Im developing a website, locally on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , with a standard LAMP installation. Finished the "tests" phase locally, i would move the db on a VPS to start doing some tests on the web. Hence, i've dumped the db with

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt example > emample.sql
```

then i've

```
scp example.sql user@host:mysqldump/
```

and then, on the VPS:

```
mysql -u root -p example > example.sql
```

well, after the password prompt i've pressed enter, but nothing happened. The cursor blinks from about 2 hours ago, but the DB size is 20kb !!!!!

Any idea of what is happening?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
mysql -u root -p example > example.sql
```

it has to be

```
mysql -u root -p example < example.sql
```

(Note the `<`).

`>` is for redirecting the output of the command to the file `example.sql`, `<` is for setting `example.sql` as input (redirect the file content to `stdin`).

Before you try that, copy the file again to your server as the command you have tried may have overwritten its content (`>` deletes the file content and begins a new file with the output of the command, only `>>` would have appended it)

Comment: what a stupid i was. This is the first time i run these commands. Thanks